# Deleting all rows except those with max date

Tags: mysql

If my schema is a table with id, uid & date like..

```
id uid date

1 10 2019-01-01 10:50:40

2 10 2019-01-02 09:20:20

3 11 2019-01-04 11:00:00

4 11 2019-01-04 08:30:30
```

Query looks like `SELECT id, max(date) FROM table GROUP BY id;`

And I returning 2 columns so get error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` as expected.

How do I return single column and then delete all other rows like `DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id, max(date) FROM table GROUP BY id)`.

Thanks

EDIT:

I figured I can `DELETE from table where id not in (SELECT id from (SELECT id, max(date) from table) a)` ????

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to delete everything except the largest date? Or just how to select a single column?

Comment: keep one row per user (latest), delete the rest. I want to list ids (not uids) before deleting though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `subquery` with `NOT IN` statement

```
delete from tableA where id not in 
(select t.id
    from (select id, max(date) maxd from tableA group by id)t)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I list ids by `select id from table where id not in (select t.id from (select id, max(date) from table group by id)t)` ?

Comment: running on 10GB table query is hanging for long time, its possible to have verbose setting to watch what its doing?

Comment: how would I wrap this in transaction? put it between `BEGIN` & `END` ? thanks